# Encountering a Problem in IntelliJ which only accepts Wildcard Imports of java packages instead of specific Classes from java packages

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Information about my Project:

- Gradle Version 6.8.3
- Lombok Version 1.18.18
- IDE Version 2020.3

My JAVA_HOME Path in the Windows environment variables is set to the newest Java JDK (15.0.2). The Project Language in the Project Structure Path is also set to Java 15.

I am currently using IntelliJ version 2020.3 and since a few days I have the following Problem.
When I want to import specific Classes or Interfaces from the *java* package e.g `java.time.LocalDate`. IntelliJ marks this import as an unused import [Unused Import java.time.LocalDate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mXIB.png)

After I replace the `LocalDate` with an Wildcard `*` the Message is gone [java.time.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFubr.png)

In the next Step I did the same with another Class I want to import. This time I used the `java.util.Set` import. The same message occurred after I wrote `Set<TestClass> foo;`. [Cannot resolve Symbol 'Set'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGQFV.png)

When I replaced the `java.util.Set` with `java.util.*` the Message disappeared. [Wildcard import for java.util](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKP94.png)

I got this Problem everytime I want to import a specific Class from the Java JDK libraries. When I import libraries from the Gradle Dependencies everythings works fine. So this Problem only occurs on Java libraries.

I Already tried the following Steps to solve the Problem:

- import Project with IntelliJ VCS
- Checked if there are any incorrect settings in Project structure
- File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart
- Project Structure -> Project SDK and added the same Java JDK again
- Ctrl + Shift + A and Restored default Settings

Code Sample:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Builder;

@Builder
@Getter
public class TestClass {
    private LocalDate testDate;
    private Set<TestClass> foo;
}
```

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Is it possible to share sample project example for investigation?

Comment: What happens when you remove the `import java.time.LocalDate` but you don't do the star import? Does intellij tell you it cannot find the symbol?

Comment: can you check what is the value of class count of import statement under `Preferences` -> `Editor` -> `Code Style` -> `Java` -> `Import` tab ?

Comment: @code_mechanic the import statement count is set to 5

Comment: Then it must not use wildcard import.

Comment: One more thing, what you have in `Packages to use Import with *` section below the count properties?

Comment: @matt I did it with another sample  in my current class. There was an `import java.util.List;` in this Class a List is used. When I remove the import IntelliJ tells me two Options in the red light bulb. One is: "Import Class" the other is "Create type parameter 'List'". I tried the first option and a new window opens where I only have the option to import from Gradle Libraries so I don´t find any Java libraries there

Comment: @code_mechanic I have there `import java.awt.*` and `import javax.swing.*` in the Tab "With subpackages" I have now ticked the tow checkboxes. Default was unchecked

Comment: Try increasing the count with `*` import to some number more than 20-30 class and then reimport your in you class file, for me this config works fine https://imgur.com/LwqPlie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Installing Eclipse and getting the same Error Reports like in IntelliJ. I reinstalled jdk 15.0.2. I reopened the project again in IntelliJ and everything worked fine. IntelliJ recommend imports when I used `java.util` classes. So I will close this question now. Thank you guys very much for trying to help me with this problem. In the end it was something much easier which fixed the problem.